# how to block the subsequent clicks in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

in angular typescript, during login and logout how do I limit the click to one, blocking the next ones?
sorry for my bad english

Comment: Sorry but to receive some help, you should consider to improve your question. What is your objective, and what is the encountered problem. Use Google Translate if needed; Thanks. It will be a pleasure to help you in this case.

Comment: they asked me to create a function that does not allow people who click on the login and logout button more than once

Comment: @Songuid supply the your attempted solution. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any example code for us to work with?

Without anything to build off of, I can't give a very specific answer, but generally speaking, in your login component you should declare a property to keep track of if the user can click the button or not. Run a function whenever for the user submits the form.

```
export class LoginComponent {
    canSubmitForm = true;

    onSubmit() {
        if(this.canSubmitForm) {
            this.canSubmitForm = false;
            // ~ YOUR CODE HERE ~
        }
    }
}
```

When you get your response from the server, you can change the value of `CanSubmitForm` to `true`, or go to another page.

In the HTML, run `onSubmit` when the `button` or `input type="button"` is clicked.

```
<button (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!canSubmitForm">Submit</button>
```

Your backend should also be checking to make sure every request is valid for security reasons. *NEVER* trust the client side!

Comment: This is good advice but the `[disabled]` in the markup renders the `if` redundant, you should remove one or the other. Also, regarding the property, the `public` modifier is redundant and PascalCasing is not idiomatic whereas camelCasing is.

Comment: The `if` is there so the Typescript can function more independently of the HTML. If the `[disabled]` was removed the code would still function as intended. You're right though, it is redundant. Everything else I completely agree with -- I've never been good at remembering casing rules

Comment: Just trying to give you some suggestions. I see what you mean about keeping the code resilient, but given how coupled the template and the TypeScript I don't see the benefit